# DRF ListSerializer Error: Expected a list of items but got type "int"

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to serialize a list of objects by passing `many=True` to the serializer. If I pass an instance instead of a list without `many=True`, the serializer works. I am still trying to understand how serializers work but having trouble debugging this issue. I am using DRF 3.3.0

**View:** (**Error in line 3 below**)

```
class BubbleExamView(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       sections = self.data.exam.section_set.all()
       if serializers.TakeSectionSerializer(
           sections, self.data.user.id, many=True).is_valid(raise_exception=True):
              sections_json = renderer.render(serializers.TakeSectionSerializer(
            sections, self.data.user.id, many=True).data)
            context = {
                'exam': self.data.exam,
                'sections_json': sections_json,
                'student': self.data.user,
                'course': self.data.exam.course,
            }
            context.update(kwargs)
       return super(BubbleExamView, self).get_context_data(**context)
       ....
       ....
```

**Serializer:**

```
class FullAssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')

    def get_image_url(self, asset):
        if asset.image:
            return default_storage.url(asset.image.name)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Asset
        fields = ('id', 'asset_type', 'text', 'image',)

class FullQuestionAssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    asset = FullAssetSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.QuestionAsset
        fields = ('id', 'order', 'asset')

class StubbedSectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serialize a section object, without any of the assets or questions"""
    class Meta:
        model = models.Section
        fields = ('id', 'exam', 'name', 'number', 'duration', 'break_duration')

class TakeSectionSerializer(StubbedSectionSerializer):
    """Serialize a section object, along with all the assets and questions that are contained in the section
    in order to display it to a student taking the exam"""
    class Meta(StubbedSectionSerializer.Meta):
        fields = StubbedSectionSerializer.Meta.fields + ('assets', 'examquestions')

    examquestions = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_exam_questions')
    assets = FullAssetSerializer(many=True)

    def __init__(self, section, user_id, **kwargs):
        super(TakeSectionSerializer, self).__init__(section, **kwargs)
        self.user_id = user_id

    def get_exam_questions(self, section):
        examquestions = section.examquestion_set.all()

        kwargs = {
            'exam_question__section_id':section.id,
            'exam_response__user_id':self.user_id,
        }
        choiceresponses = models.ChoiceQuestionResponse.objects.filter(**kwargs)
        textresponses = models.TextQuestionResponse.objects.filter(**kwargs)

        for eq, response in utils.zip_responses(
            examquestions,
            itertools.chain(choiceresponses, textresponses),
            'exam_question_id'
        ):
            eq.response = response

        return ExamQuestionSerializer(examquestions, many=True).data
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback:
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  145.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/chalktalk/shared/view_utils.py" in dispatch
  21.         return super(CheckPermissionsMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in get
  158.         context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
File "/vagrant/Devel/chalktalk-legacy/chalktalk/chalktalk/apps/exams_sat/views_take.py" in get_context_data
  508.             sections, self.data.user.id, many=True).is_valid(raise_exception=True):
File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/chalktalk-legacy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in is_valid
  221.             raise ValidationError(self.errors)

Exception Type: ValidationError at /sat/474/208/bubble/
Exception Value: {u'non_field_errors': [u'Expected a list of items but got type "int".']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in just the user id to the serializer as your data, and the serializer is complaining because that's definitely not the right data format.

```
if serializers.TakeSectionSerializer(
       sections, self.data.user.id, many=True).is_valid(raise_exception=True):
```

Serializers are expecting a full dictionary of data (keys being the serializer fields), and they are expecting a list of dictionaries if you specify `many=True`. You are only passing in a single value, the id of a user, instead of a list of dictionaries. Because of this, DRF is complaining that it was only given an integer instead of a list of items.

I'd recommend [looking at the DRF tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) for a better understanding of how serialization works.

Answer (score 0):

I won't take credit for this, but this is the answer that worked and was answered by the DRF folks in their github issues.

"*I checked the Serializer code inside DRF, and we are overriding `__new__` which means your `__init__` constructor override is useless (the magic happens before that). Here is that line of code in the DRF source
I would suggest you to remove `__init__` inside TakeSectionSerializer. Instead you should pass the self.user.id inside a context `TakeSectionSerializer(sections, context={'user_id': self.user.id}, many=True)` and modify your TakeSectionSerializer code accordingly.*

*If you don't know how to get the context so you can use it in your get_exam_questions, you may want to check out our "Including extra context" example. Basically `self.context['user_id']` should work.
That will definitely take care of your problem.*"